# read xml using file get contents

Tags: php

i hv a xml file,how to get values in title field using get file content method..i just want to get the value "TomTom XXL 550M - US, Canada & Mexico Automotive GPS. (Brand New)"

```
<Title>
TomTom XXL 550M - US, Canada & Mexico Automotive GPS. (Brand New)
</Title>
```

my code

```
$xmlstr = file_get_contents($source);
$parseXML = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
print($parseXML);

// load as file
$parseXMLFile = new SimpleXMLElement($source,null,true);
```

Comment: [Basic SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) from PHP.net

Comment: just use http://php.net/manual/de/function.simplexml-load-file.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you feel confortable with javascript, there is another solution called [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

You can load XML files and also use function like getElementsByTagName. For example, if you have a books.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<books>
 <book><title>Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture</title></book>
 <book><title>Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Software Design</title></book>
 <book><title>Clean Code</title></book>
</books>
```

You can extract titles so:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('books.xml');
$books = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');
foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo $book->nodeValue.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just have to read your file with `simplexml_load_file` : [Doc for this one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

You will then get object of class `SimpleXMLElement`.

Then, you can use it to get what you want ! Some examples here : [SimpleXML Examples](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)